# Which test to use for paired samples with different sizes and only 1 categorical variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, sample

I am testing 9 rooms for bacteria growth, and want to see affects of heat. Assume Blue Room is colder, Red room is warmer.

[image]

I am not sure how to approach this because

- samples are too small (so can't assume normality)
- sample sizes differ even without groups

The n for each room is how many times we swabbed each room, and we counted how many bacteria were on each swab. So if n=7, it means that we swabbed 7 times in room 1 Blue, with an average bacteria count in each one of 3.7. N=8 the second time, because we swabbed 8 times.

However, I believe there is significance - the Blue rooms clearly see less change than the red rooms, I just need to prove this. I did some research but unfortunately an ANOVA or Wilcoxon paired test don't seem to help me here, as I want to show the categorical variable (Red/Blue) has a statistically significant effect.

Any help is appreciated, and sorry if this question is trivial - I don't have a statistics ba

Comment: How do you have $n=7$ (or whatever) in one room? What does that mean?

Comment: @Dave I will clarify in the main post

Comment: To deal with this properly, you don't just average the values, since their standard deviation would also matter. I'd be very wary of assuming either that the variances are constant after averaging (how could that work?) *or* that the variances are constant across temperature (when you'd instead tend to expect variability in some measure of growth to relate to the amount of growth).

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I have posted a question with additional clarification, appreciate it if you could take a look. Thanks https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469336/which-test-to-use-for-non-normal-paired-data-with-different-sample-sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This experiment seems to have been planned on the spur of the moment (if there was any planning at all). Different numbers of swabs were used in
different rooms before and after. The likely effect is that
the smaller number of swabs in each comparison is the number
that matters.

You are correct that sample sizes here are quite
small---so small that meaningful tests of normality are impossible.
Moreover, the number of Blue rooms is too small to get meaningful
results from rank-based nonparametric tests comparing Before and After, so the only
alternative there is to hope that data are nearly enough normal that
t tests can give useful P-values.

A crucial part of any experiment is to decide, before taking any data, how much data is required in order to detect effects that
are large enough to be of practical importance, and to decide
what tests will be used for the analysis.

Undoubtedly, there is a GLM ANOVA that could
take account of the different samples sizes, but I don't believe
results of it would lead to different conclusions than my
very rough approximate procedures below. (All procedures below are done using R.)

**Before vs. after.** To begin, consider only the Blue rooms.
Equal numbers of swabs (instead of, for example, 7,7,5; 8,6,6) on each day in each room, you could treat the the three means for Blue rooms
Before and the three means after as data for a paired t.test.
Perhaps you would do a one-sample t test on the three differences, as follows:

```
t.test(c(-.1, .7, .4), alte="gr")

        One Sample t-test

data:  c(-0.1, 0.7, 0.4)
t = 1.4286, df = 2, p-value = 0.1447
alternative hypothesis: 
   true mean is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.3479966        Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.3333333
```

So according to this approximate procedure, we see no
significant difference in Blue rooms from Before to After.
(Procedures are approximate mainly because the three differences are from populations with differing variances.)

*And for Red rooms:* If we use the same kind of approximate procedure, treating
the Before - After difference for each room, regardless
of the number of swabs went into producing those differences,
we could test Red rooms to see if there is a significant Before/After difference.

```
t.test(c(2.6, 2.3, 1.6, 1.8, 3/1, 3/4), alt="gr")$p.val
[1] 0.000833765
wilcox.test(c(2.6, 2.3, 1.6, 1.8, 3/1, 3/4), alt="gr")$p.val
[1] 0.015625
```

**Blue vs. red rooms.** Then we might compare differences for Blue rooms with differences for red rooms using an approximate 2-sample t test (based on observations of unequal variance, even *within* in each sample).

```
b = c(-.1, .7, .4);  r = c(2.6, 2.3, 1.6, 1.8, 3/1, 3/4)
t.test(b, r, alt="less")

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  b and r
t = -4.1678, df = 6.9106, p-value = 0.00216
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is less than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
       -Inf -0.9121077
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.3333333 2.0083333
```

A two-sample Wilcoxon test also shows a significant difference.
Reasons why this test can be only approximate are more subtle than for the t test, but no less valid.

```
wilcox.test(b, r, alt="less")$p.val
[1] 0.01190476
```

**Results are only tentative.** Results from this study may be useful in planning a properly
designed experiment of the effect of temperature on bacteria growth in such rooms. However, I would not advise taking them as
evidence to persuade anyone outside of your immediate group.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for the help. It was brought to my attention that SD of these samples may help with statistical testing, I have posted a question with clarification. Appreciate it if you could take a look. Thanks https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469336/which-test-to-use-for-non-normal-paired-data-with-different-sample-sizes

Comment: Yes, standard deviations (not revealed here) can help in weighting observations. (For paired differences, it it the pairs that need to be weighted.) As this question stands, too many unwarranted assumptions need to be made in order to deduce SDs and to do sensible weighting. I assumed you would have given SDs if you had them. // Thanks for the new post, which I will leave to someone else to answer.