# Which test to use for non-normal paired data, with different sample sizes?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, sample

I posted a similar question yesterday, but was brought to my attention that I may need to consider the variance of my samples.

I swabbed 9 rooms (3 cold/6 hot) for bacteria. The bacteria was counted on each swab, and then a week later after a  chemical cleaning, I did the same thing. However, the # of times I swabbed (sample size) changes each time. I understand this is not a perfect experiment set-up, but re-doing the experiment is not an option currently.

I have outlined the average bacteria count, along with SD of each test. 
[image]

I have noticed that cold rooms seem to see less difference than warm rooms. This was what I expected to see, I just need a statistical method to back up my findings.
Any help is appreciated, and sorry if this question is trivial - I don't have a statistics background.

Comment: Do you have the raw data available?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post all of the detailed sample data due to confidentiality issues. @DemetriPananos

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've done my best to simulate your data.  I'll be doing the analysis in R.  Here is a sample

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   temps    id times      y
   <chr> <int> <chr>  <int>
 1 warm      6 before     3
 2 warm      6 before     5
 3 warm      6 before     3
 4 warm      6 later      5
 5 warm      5 later      4
 6 warm      8 later      2
 7 warm      9 before     3
 8 warm      5 before     1
 9 warm      4 before     0
10 cold      2 before     0
```

The rooms have been sampled multiple times, before and after under both warm and cool temps.  Because the data are counts and because rooms are measured several times, we can use a generalized mixed effects model.  It is a bit technical, but from what you've told me I think this is the best approach.  The model essentially assumes that the effect of temperature and time are fixed; they effect the outcome in the same way regardless of room.  However, each room has their own baseline average number of bacteria.  Here is how I might fit my model.

```
model = glmer(y~temps + times + (1|id), data = dd, family = poisson())
```

If you are interested in the effect of temp, we just look at the coefficient.  The coefficients can be found by using the `summary` function.

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: y ~ temps + times + (1 | id)
   Data: dd

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   705.8    718.4   -348.9    697.8      172 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8210 -0.7227 -0.1048  0.6206  3.8707 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0.007315 0.08553 
Number of obs: 176, groups:  id, 9

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.76388    0.10464   7.300 2.88e-13 ***
tempswarm    0.48910    0.11188   4.372 1.23e-05 ***
timeslater   0.22572    0.08202   2.752  0.00593 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) tmpswr
tempswarm  -0.770       
timeslater -0.418 -0.001
```

The coefficient of `tempwarm` is 0.49 which means that on average the counts will increase by a factor of $\exp(0.49)=1.63$ when compared to colder rooms.  Cold rooms in the before period have an average count of $\exp(0.76)=2.13$, so that means warm rooms in the before period have a count of $2.14\cdot 1.63 = 3.48$.

I can help you implement this if you like.  I know the details can be kind of tricky.  Just let me know

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I fully follow. The tibble you provided seems off, none of the samples have an average bacteria count of 0. Also, I should have clarified, but time is not necessarily a factor in the study, but rather a cleaning solution. We set bacteria in a cold or hot room, sprayed some cleaning solution, and measured bacteria again afterwards. Hopes this clarifies some things.

Comment: I've simulated this data just to exposit how I might solve this.  The solution is not necessarily simple, especially because your background may not be statistics.  Through from the details you've given me, I think this is the most defensible way to approach the problem.  You can try messaging me directly and I can help as much as I can

Comment: Okay, to clarify, my "temperature" is essentially the room environment. Some rooms may have A/C, or be in a heavily populated area, or in a rural farm environment. Do these effects (from the room type) count as random or fixed effects?

Comment: Hard to say unless I know more about the design.  Do you not have measurements on the actual temperature in each room?